# How do I get the output of a SELECT statements in MariaDB/MySQL workbench to name columns in "table.column" format instead of just "column"?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have to explore undocumented schemas to come up with query statements that will satisfy some business need.

When I SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.barid=bar.id; I get back a list of columns and I could guess where the columns from one table end and the next begin.  But it would be awfully convenient if it just used the columns' full names i the output.  i.e, every column would display as foo.columnname or bar.columnname.

yes, that's bulkier than optimal, and no I'd never use it in a production solution.  but for exploratory pokings and prodings it would make things easier when I'm trying to figure out why a query isn't working right.
How do I turn that on by default?

CLARIFICATION: No.  I'm not looking for "how to list all columns in a table/schema.  I want to run queries joining tables together, and see the results, and see unambiguously and easily, what table a given field came from.

Comment: There is no such option. You should know your table schema beforehand, before running queries. You can use, for example, a command like `show table <mytable>` to list the columns of a table.

Comment: Never use evil `SELECT *`. Just select (qualify, and alias) only the columns you actually want returned

Comment: @Strawberry - To "explore" a table, `SELECT *` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the database information_schema to help you figure out what is what in your database. Running the following will get you close:

```
select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

Comment: "Exploring" usually involves seeing the data, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use * you can qualify by table for example

```
select foo.*,'//',bar.*
```

will display all columns from foo first then a divider then all columns from bar and within foo the display left to right represents the ordinal position of the columns in foo. If the display columns are left justified then the column datatype is string of some description (varchar,char,text etc) if right justified then a number of some sort (int,decimal,float etc) . If a number is left justified then the underlying datatype is string. Date datatypes in mysql are in the form yyyy-mm-dd so if you see this then the underlying dataype is likely to be date. Similarly datetime

To understand the actual datatypes and find the indexes,constraints and foreign keys on a table then show create table tablename . If you want all table definitions use workbench export or mysqldump utility.

Also do read up on what information_schema https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html can do for you and consider reverse engineering your DB in workbench.

Comment: This Answer addresses the "explore" part of the Question.